RAM usage TensorFlow
I am doing an AI project on TensorFlow, I have copied the code from the net. Issue is that when I try to fit the model, it uses up all of the RAM provided(12.7GB) I am running it on Google Colab.
My code:
history=model.fit(
    train_ds,
    epochs=EPOCHS,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    verbose=1,
    validation_data=val_ds
)

train_ds is a list containing 20665 images
epochs=50
batch_size=32
val_ds is a list containing 2583 images.
What should I do to resolve this issue? It fills up the RAM within the first 30 seconds or so and does not even begin the execution. Also the images are pre-processed to be 256x256

Have you tried lowering batch size? Decreasing the batch size decreases the memory used by the forward pass.

Do you know that this model can normally be fit in 12.7 GB of memory? What did the person who originally fit this use?

Yes, I tried changing the batch size and a lot of stuff. It finally worked yesterday after making some code optimizations, reducing the batch size to 2, and reducing the images from 256x256 to 128x128. It technically created the model but the accuracy was so trash that it was only slightly better than randomly choosing. Redoing it again to see if the accuracy can improve.
